# How to solve this one-sided constraint problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, constrained-dynamics

As shown in the figure below, ball 1 and ball 2 are connected by a rigid rod without mass. The wall and floor are absolutely smooth, and the mass of ball 1 and ball 2 are all $m$.

[image]

The other geometric parameters are represented in the graph. I want to know how to establish the motion differential equation of this one-sided constraint problem and analyze its motion.
I use the dynamic simulation software to simulate the following process, and the motion track is as follows：

[image]

How can I use analytical mechanics to solve this one-sided constraint problem?

Comment: Why are you getting bouncing motion?

Comment: This is a typical and interesting question!

Comment: @G.Smith Because the wall is a single-sided constraint, and the ball will bounce back at the original speed when it collides with the ground, and the ball 1 will move away from the wall, resulting in a trajectory of bounce, which is a continuous process.

Comment: What is the definition of a “single-sided constraint”?

Comment: @G.Smith Single-sided constraint is to restrict the movement of an object only in one direction, while the other side is unlimited. Its mathematical description is an inequality, such as the wall, the object has the freedom to break away from the wall, rather than sticking to the wall all the time.